# not able to see the validation summary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a got a requirement like i need to show validation summary on top of page for that i have done like this in my view

```
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.CrossFieldValidation
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}    
<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true) // here I have mentioned that validation summary true
 but its not showing all messages in bulleted list 
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostValues", "CrossFieldsTxtboxes"))
{          
    <div class ="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TxtCrossField)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.TxtCrossField)
    </div>
   <div class =".editor-field">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.SelectedValue , Model.Items)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SelectedValue)
   </div>
    <div class ="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.ShippingValue)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ShippingValue) 
    </div>
    <div class =".editor-field">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.SelectedShippingItemValue , Model.Items)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SelectedShippingItemValue)
   </div>
    <div class ="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.DeliverPrice)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.DeliverPrice)
    </div>
    <div class =".editor-field">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.SelectedDeliveredItem , Model.Items)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SelectedDeliveredItem)
   </div>       
    <div class=".editor-field">
          <input id="PostValues" type="Submit" value="PostValues" />
        </div>
}
```

at present i am able to show the error messages near to drop down list and textbox but i want it at the top of page for that purpose what changes do i need to do in my view 
would any one pls suggest any ideas ..
Many thanks in advance....

Note : I am using razor view engine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code into your `web.config`. It will work

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Updated

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Comment: @pratapk you want validation as a summary or in front of control

Comment: Try @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

Comment: one more little bit question i want to show star near to textbox how its possible

Comment: Before text box starting or end of text box so I will provide exact answer

Comment: For display star
    <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #D00045;">*</span>

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to put all your `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Items)`

right below

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

and put this code where you want it on the page.